# how set the value of check box getting from arraylist objects

Tags: java, jsp

I'm processing a multi form page from jsp. And I have to display checkbox in table format having value=id which is getting from ResultSet in  ArrayList object. So my question is how to display check box with each row setting in value= id. And row (record) is coming from ArrayList.

The code in my JSP is :

```
        <center>
<div style="margin:20px 0px 0px 0px; width:1100px; height:450px; background-color:lightgray" class="divBorder ">
    <font color="#3B5998"><h3>Work Description</h3>
    <table style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px; border:solid 2px darkGray; border-spacing:5px " border="1"></font>
    <tr><th width="20px">Select</th><th width="60px">Work Code</th>
            <th width="700px">Description</th><th width="60px">Edit</th></tr>
    <%
    Work_Manager wm=new Work_Manager();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> worklist=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    worklist=wm.getWork();
    Iterator<ArrayList<Object>> it = worklist.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){%>
        <tr>
    <%  
        list=it.next();
        Iterator<Object> itr = list.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){%>
        <td>
        <%=itr.next()%></td>
        <% }%>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td></tr>
    <%
    }
    %>


    </table>
    <table style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;">
        <tr><td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Delete Selected List" onclick="" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the `ResultSet` object from `ArrayList`.

```
Resultset rs = (Resultset) iter.next();

while(rs.next()){ 
String value = rs.getString("your column name for id");
%>
<tr>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name="abc" value="<%=value%>">
<td>....</td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
```

Pass this `value` dynamically while creating table.

Comment: Actually I'm already constructing ArrayList from ResultSet objects and then displaying them in HTML table in this JSP... So now the problem is with check box... how to display this checkbox here,...? using same Arraylist. Should I execute separate loop for populating the checkbox having value=ID...?

Comment: use same for loop.In while loop, get the resultset object as mentioned above and  column for check box value.Create a <tr> <td> and one of the column will be for check box.updated my answer.